# Proving the infimum and supremum of a well-ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem:** Let $S$ be a well-ordered set. Prove that $\text{supremum} = \bigcup S$. and $\text{infimum} = \bigcap S$.

**My attempt at proving the statement:**

1. Supremum: 1) $\bigcup S$ is upper bound which means $M\subseteq \bigcup S$, $\forall M \in S$. Lets assume that $\exists M \in S : \bigcup S \subseteq M => \exists m \in M : m\notin \bigcup S$ - impossible because of the struture of $\bigcup S$ 2)$\bigcup S$ is least upper bound which means $(if \exists T : C \subseteq T, \forall C \in \bigcup S )(1)=> \bigcup S \subseteq T.$ Lets assume $\exists T \subseteq \bigcup S => \exists P \in S : T \subseteq P$ which is contradiction to (1).
2. Infimum: 1)$\bigcap S$ is lower bound which means $\bigcap S \subseteq C, \forall C \in S$. Lets assume $\exists C' \in S : C' \subseteq \bigcap S => \exists s \in \bigcap S$ : $s \notin C'$ - contradiction. 2) Greatest lower bound: Lets assume that $\exists I' \in S : I' \subseteq C, \forall C \in S$ and $I' \subseteq \bigcap S => \exists i \in \bigcap S : i \notin I'$ - contradiction.

This proof seems to me rather insufficient or even incorrect. Could someone review it or propose improvements? Thanks!

**Edit**: The binary relation is inclusion.

Comment: Are all well ordered sets assumed to have their orderings as inclusion?

Comment: @coffeemath Ok, lets add the condition that the relation is inclusion then.

Comment: Looks good, but in your contradiction style proof that U(S) is an upper bound, you maybe should explicitly assume it is not, and choose M in S for which U(S) is a *proper* subset of M.

Comment: Looks fine to me,but the language ends up being a little awkward because you don't do the usual proof by contradiction,so coffeemath gave you some good advice to follow.